# Nashorn script caching

Tags: java, nashorn

Is there a way to cache script evaluated in `Nashorn` to avoid evaluating same script twice?

For example I have some js library that does something. I want to evaluate Library once and reuse it on every file I want to.

```
public void modifyFile(String inputFile){
    scriptEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    bindings = scriptEngine.createBindings();
    scriptEngine.eval(new FileReader("css-lib.js"),bindings);
    bindings.put(INPUT, readFile(inputFilePath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    scriptEngine.getContext().setWriter(new StringWriter());
    executeScript(COMPRESS_SCRIPT_PATH, scriptEngine, bindings);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you "eval" on same script twice, Nashorn engine will run that script twice! But evaluating twice does not imply compiling (to bytecode) twice. Nashorn does cache compiled representation and reuses.